# Dúvida com Ponteiros em C

Tags: c, ponteiro

Tenho uma lista encadeada, com um único variável que é o data(int).
Fiz essa função para deletar por valor.

```
lista *head = NULL;

void deletar(int valor) {

    lista *prev, *temp = head;
    if(temp->data == valor) {
        head = temp->prox;
        free(temp);
    } else {
        while(temp->data != valor && temp != NULL) {
            prev = temp;
            temp = temp->prox;
        }
        prev->prox = temp->prox;
        free(temp);
    }
}
```

Mas não estou entendo porque quando troco:
 `prev->prox = temp->prox;` por  `temp = temp->prox;` 
Não funciona corretamente, já que `prev->prox` e `temp`, possuem o mesmo endereço de memória. Endereco: 0x14d3050 e 0x14d3050

Comment: O que exatamente "não funciona"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prev` e `temp` são ponteiros. Ou seja, são variáveis, que vivem em seu próprio endereço de memória, cujo valor é um endereço para outro lugar na memória.

```
int x = 5; // variável com o valor 5
int *y = &x; // variável cujo valor é o endereço de memória da variável x
*y = 6; // Atribui o valor 6 no endereço de memória armazenado em y.
        // ou seja, a x.
```

`prev->prox` é equivalente a `(*prev).prox`. Em `prev->prox = temp->prox;` você está dizendo:

1. Pegue o valor armazenado no local de memória apontado por `prev`
2. Esse valor é uma *struct* que, entre outras coisas, possui um endereço de memória chamado `prox`
3. Atribua à `prox` o endereço de memória que está em `(*temp).prox`

#### Visualmente

Estado inicial:

```
-- [ prev ] -- [ elemento a excluir ] -- [ prox ]
                          ^
                         temp
```

Estado final:

```
-- [ prev ] -- [ prox ]

temp > [ elemento a excluir ]
```

Ou seja, o nó anterior vai apontar para o próximo de `temp`. O que significa que a lista original irá *pular* o nó para qual `temp` está apontando. Você então libera a área de memória para qual `temp` aponta na linha seguinte e `temp` sai de escopo.

Já em `temp = temp->prox;` você está fazendo `temp` apontar para seu próximo elemento. Nesse caso você está mudando o endereço para o qual a variável `temp` está apontando. Seria o equivalente a fazer:

```
int z = 6;
y = &z;
```

Veja que `x` nesse caso continua sendo 5. Você mudou o endereço para qual `y` aponta e não o conteúdo de `x`.

Da mesma forma, nada acontece com `prev->prox` pelo fato de você ter mudado o endereço para o qual `temp` aponta. `prev->prox` ainda está apontando para o endereço do nó que você estava querendo excluir.

E o pior: `temp` agora está apontando para o próximo elemento (logo depois do elemento que você pretendia excluir):

Na próxima linha você está chamando `free(temp)`. Nesse caso:

1. Você está liberando memória do endereço do elemento errado
2. `[elemento a excluir]->prox` aponta para uma área de memória que você liberou.

#### Visualmente

Estado inicial:

```
-- [ prev ] -- [ elemento a excluir ] -- [ prox ]
                                            ^
                                           temp
```

Estado final:

```
-- [ prev ] -- [ elemento que deveria ter sido excluido ] --
```

Comment: Assim: prev->prox , está pegando o endereço de prev, e não de prev->prox ? porque era essa a minha confusão.

Comment: `prev->prox` pega o endereço do próximo elemento após o anterior. Ou seja, quando você encontra o elemento a ser excluído, `temp` e `prev->prov` apontam para o mesmo endereço de memória (conforme o próprio enunciado da sua pergunta).  A confusão está em achar que `temp = algo`  é equivalente a `prev->prox = algo`, os dois ponteiros são independentes mesmo que em um momento anterior estivessem apontando para o mesmo lugar. Faz sentido?